# Should I use Laravel Middleware?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, middleware

I have a Laravel app that requires getting some config vars that need to be used by most of my controllers.
Therefore it seems like this would be the perfect time to use middleware.
Is this the correct use of middleware? and if so, once the middleware gets the config vars, is it best practice to add these to the request object so they can be accessed by my controller?
Thanks to any responders.
J

Comment: Are the config vars static or dynamic.

Comment: Once they've been defined within the middleware they are static.

Comment: Can you add more information as to what you are using the variables for, how long they will last, etc.

Comment: You can use middleware to set configuration variables. It doesn't have to be used for restricting access. It can be used to group several routes and to expose certain values to them, while restricting those config values to other routes. You have the option to set these variables however you like. It's not wrong to use it the way you wanted to.

Comment: Thanks N.B. for your response. I guess I'm really trying to figure out when to use which approach. i.e. Is it best practice to use middleware, a base controller or as felipsmartins suggests a service provider. (I'm really struggling on when to use a service provider!)

Answer (score 2):

Not, definitely!

Actually (based on you've written), the best way to go is creating an application service and registering this service on Service Container  -  `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` (in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`).

Something like this:

```
<?php
# The Config Service:

namespace App\Services;

/**
 * Config Manager
 */
class Config
{
    /** @var SomeDependency */
    protected $dependency;

    public function __construct(SomeDependency $dependency)
    {
        $this->dependency = $dependency;
    }

    public function getVar($var)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In your Service Provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    //...

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

        $this->registerConfigManager();

    }

    public function registerConfigManager()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('config_service', function ($app) {
            return new \App\Services\Config(new \SomeNamespace\SomeDependency);
        });
    }

    //...
}
```

And now you can to access the service container via `app()`, like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        app('config_service')->getVar('key');
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks felipsmartins, Are others in agreement that this would be a good time to use a service provider?

Comment: @jon Actually, it's not need to create a service provider but just create an class and then register it as a application service in container. That's simple and a nice way to go.

Comment: Thanks both, this is where i'm getting really confused, it is when it is best practice to use middleware, a service provider, or simply add the logic to the controller. Effectively the service provider is a way to make a service globally accessible?.. or am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, with this solution, the provider will be accessible in the application context. its up to you to decide wich solution better suits you: access in the application context or controller context

Comment: @jon Just think of Middlewares like HTTP filter for on-going requests. Services are just simple classes/objects reused through application context, in multiple places (i.e.: Mailer service). Regarding controller logic be aware in this case you will not *reuse* the logic or procedure inside another controller.

Comment: Thanks @felipsmartins. So if I needed to use the config vars else where in my code then I should use the service provider approach. It would really helpful if there was a best practices examples of real life examples of when to use which laravel approach. Thanks again for your responses. J

Comment: @jon Also, if everything what you need is a simple bunch of vars/parameters, you could to create a custom config file under config directory and then access by `config('custom_config_filename.youvar)` or even at `config/app.php`

Comment: Thanks @felipsmartins, however the config data wouldn't be hardcoded but stored in a DB, so I assume a service provider would be better solution. Just to clarify I would use a service provider for things like a Mailer, or in this example a way to get my config vars... i.e. anything that my controllers might need to use in their logic.

Comment: @jon Yep! You're rigth. A global service would be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, middlewares are made for pre-processing requests, restrict user access, and other security related.

I would simply load the configuration in the main Controller class and use it in the extending controllers.

For example:

*base controller*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

uses goes here ...;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    protected $configs = [];

    public function __construct() {
        $this->loadConfigs();
    }

    protected function loadConfigs()
    {
        //read configuration files or tables in database 
        //and put the values into '$this->configs';
    }

}
```

*user controller*

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;

class User extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo $this->configs['toolbar.color']; //just an example
    }
}
```

Comment: Middleware exists to check conditions before letting requests reach your controllers. They are used for preprocessing **and** postprocessing. It's not security related, it's condition related (one condition can be "user has to be authenticated). It can be used for setting variables and everything needed before request reaches the controller. This comment is here to highlight that your statement about middleware being used for security isn't true.

Comment: Perfect thanks Carlos, that makes sense, so basically just use middleware for filtering and put the logic that may be needed by most of my controllers in a base controller. That sits well in my head :)

Comment: Though I see N.B disagrees. So N.B. would you add my requirements as midldleware?

Comment: IMHO, this should be the way to go, in your case. If you have to process something, middlewares are the way to go. But, in this case, seems you don't need to do that.